# Replacing content in a text file if it matches patterns while leaving non-matches Intact

Tags: powershell, text, replace

I have a text file where I need to edit some rows, but the script only outputs the rows that were edited. I want the output to be the original file, just with the rows I want to edit being the only thing that changes.
My file is tab delimited and looks like this

```
File.txt  
ABC 123456 987654321 DEF 0 More Text  
ABC 123457 987654320 DEF 0 More Text  
XYZ 123457 987654320 DEF 0 More Text
```

I want the file to output this

```
ABC 123456 987654321 DEF 0 More Text  
ABC 123457 987654320 GHI 1 More Text  
XYZ 123457 987654320 DEF 0 More Text
```

This is what I have.
$arrExcelValues is an array of values pulled from an excel file

```
foreach ($file in $files){
    get-content -Path $file | 
             where {$_ | Select-String -Pattern '^ABC.+'}| 
             where {$_ | Select-String -Pattern $arrExcelValues} | % {$_ -replace "DEF`t0","GHI`t1"} | Set-Content $out
}
```

Powershell Identifies the rows to edit based on matching patterns, but my output is just the edited row

```
ABC 123457 987654320 GHI 1 More Text
```

I believe that the issue is that where is filtering out everything that is not a match, but once the matching rows have been changed, I can't figure out how to get an output with all of the original file contents & my edited rows

Comment: `$arrExcelValues` is an array? What column would it match?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala it matches the 2nd column, in my example 132457 would be stored in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Select-String` and `Where-Object` *filter* their input, so by definition you will only get *filtered* (potentially modified) output, not *all* input.

As an aside:

- `Import-Csv` / `Export-Csv` can process TSV (tab-separated values) data as well, using `` -Delimiter "`t" ``
- However, you may have to supply *headers* via the `-Headers` parameter, and in *Windows PowerShell* you'll invariably get *double-quoted* fields in the output (you can opt-out in *Powershell (Core) 7+*).
- The convenience of OOP processing via these cmdlets comes at the cost of diminished performance.

Sticking with your plain-text parsing approach, I suggest using a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement, which allows you to combine selective processing with passing *all* (potentially modified) lines through; as an added bonus, `switch -File` is *faster* than a `Get-Content`-based pipeline:

```
# Simulate file input as an array of lines.
$lines = @'
ABC 123456  987654321   DEF 0   More    Text
ABC 123457  987654320   DEF 0   More    Text
XYZ 123457  987654320   DEF 0   More    Text
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# The values to match the 2nd column against.
$arrExcelValues = '123457'

# Note:
#  * The following outputs to the *display* by default.
#  * Replace `($lines)` with `-File $file` in your code.
#  * Wrap the entire statement in `& { ... }` so you can pipe to `Set-Content`
#    * Use `$(...)` instead if you want to write back to the input file.
switch -Regex ($lines) {
  '^ABC\t' {
    $fields = $_ -split "`t"
    if ($fields[1] -in $arrExcelValues) {
      $fields[3] = 'GHI'
      $fields[4] = 1
      $fields -join "`t"
    } else {
      $_ # pass through
    }
  }
  default { $_ } # pass through
}
```

Comment: This definitely got the job done! I had made some attempts at using switch before, but couldn't get the syntax down. Will definitely have to read more on it, as it was very useful in this case.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @InquisitorLu. `switch` is somewhat complex, but quite flexible.